Dynamic selection of command buffer updates
For submitting Vulkan rendering commands via VkQueueSubmit(), I know that most renderers just rebuild the cmdbufs every frame, since that makes it simpler to deal with dynamic scenes.
However, I wanted to challenge myself to build a renderer that only updates/invalidates the cmdbufs as needed, and reuses them otherwise.
For something like a 3d editor, there are some aspects of the scene which remain the same for a while, and there are others aspects, like immediate-mode gui rendering (ImGui), which requires updating the cmdbufs for the gui pass every frame. That's fine.
I built the machinery to allow me to build cmds on demand, and to reuse cmdbufs that don't change. The initial version either reuses all the previously built commands, or rebuilds them all -- complete reuse or complete rebuild. But, I did put in the scafolding to do partial scene updates, but it requires extra functionality not yet present to fully work.
Recently, I started working on isolating the GUI pass such that it gets updated by itself, without having to rebuild all the commands.
My first crack was changing the frame's pass composition from this:
 # All these commands are recorded within a primary cmdbuf.
|==================== RenderPass =====================|
| Subpass0(scene) | Subpass1(Gui) | Subpass2(Present) |

Into this:
 # All cmds within 1 primary, except the secondary cmdbuf stuff
|==================== RenderPass =====================|
| Subpass0(scene) | Subpass1(Gui) | Subpass2(Present) |
        |               |                 |            
 In primary cmdbuf,  In secondary,  Back to primary 

While building that, I realized that the following requirement precludes from doing that.

VUID-vkCmdExecuteCommands-contents-06018
If vkCmdExecuteCommands is being called within a render pass instance
begun with vkCmdBeginRenderPass, its contents parameter must have been set to
VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_SECONDARY_COMMAND_BUFFERS ,
or VK_SUBPASS_CONTENTS_INLINE_AND_SECONDARY_COMMAND_BUFFERS_EXT

This means that, without the extension VK_EXT_nested_command_buffer, it's not possible to have a RenderPass which has a mixture of Subpasses created in primary and secondary cmdbufs. The RenderPass must contain subpasses made-up of either secondary cmdbufs, or only of primary cmdbufs, but not both.
My next attempt was to change the pass composition to this:
# The renderpasses themselves are written in 1 primary cmdbuf
# There is a vkExecuteCmds() in RenderPass1
||== RenderPass0 ==|| ||== RenderPass1 ==|| ||== RenderPass2 ==|
|  Subpass(scene)  |  |   Subpass(Gui)   |  | Subpass(Present) |
         |                    |                      |          
 In primary cmdbuf,     In secondary,         Back to primary 

Before building this, I tried reading the Spec to see if this would work, but I didn't find an answer. So, I decided to try it and see.
The idea is to record a primary cmdbuf once, with the general composition of the frame. The Gui subpass is built in a secondary cmdbuf, in its own RenderPass. Then, next frame, the secondary cmdbuf gets rebuilt, but the primary remains intact.
When I tried to run this, I got this error:
Validation Error: [ VUID-vkQueueSubmit-pCommandBuffers-00070 ] 

Object 0: handle = 0x24474d05b40, name = CmdBuf2nd:0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER; 
Object 1: handle = 0x24474bcdd00, name = CmdBuf:0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER; 
| MessageID = 0xaeecdc0b | vkQueueSubmit(): 
pSubmits[0].pCommandBuffers[0] was called in VkCommandBuffer 0x24474bcdd00[CmdBuf:0] 
which is invalid because bound VkCommandBuffer 0x24474d05b40[CmdBuf2nd:0]
 was destroyed or rerecorded. 

The Vulkan spec states: Each element of the pCommandBuffers member of each element of pSubmits must be in the pending or executable state 
(https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.htm

It seems that the primary cmdbuf must be recreated whenever the secondary cmdbuf changes. This is the kind of info I was looking for in the Spec, but couldn't find it.
The only combination that I think I haven't tried is recording the subpasses to secondary cmdbufs, re-recording the primary cmdbuf every frame, and maybe only re-recording the gui secondary cmdbuf every frame, while keeping the other 2 subpasses intact.
I think the Spec could use more clarity on this reusability business.
For those of you that have successfully attempted something like this, what was your approach?


This means that, without the extension VK_EXT_nested_command_buffer, it's not possible to have a RenderPass which has a mixture of Subpasses created in primary and secondary cmdbufs. The RenderPass must contain subpasses made-up of either secondary cmdbufs, or only of primary cmdbufs, but not both.

Based on the wording of that VU rule, that is a logical conclusion. However, it is contradicted by other areas of the standard:

Possible values of vkCmdBeginRenderPass::contents, specifying how the commands in the first subpass will be provided, are:

Emphasis added. This clearly indicates that vkCmdBeginRenderPass::contents is only supposed to apply to the first subpass. Note also that vkCmdNextSubpass also gets a contents field that has the same meaning:

contents specifies how the commands in the next subpass will be provided, in the same fashion as the corresponding parameter of vkCmdBeginRenderPass

So the clear intent of these two things is that your original use case is intended to work. A particular subpass can be inline or from secondary CBs as you see fit. But this only applies to that subpass.
It should be noted that all 3 of these sections of the standard are basically unchanged from even version 1.0 of Vulkan. So this inconsistency appears to have been there for a while.
I would suggest trying the obvious solution (match your vkCmdExecuteCommands with the contents for the subpass in question) and seeing if the validation layer complains.

I bit the bullet and did the tests. It is possible to use both primary and secondary cmdbufs in the same renderpass. I attached my findings as a response to this thread. I also mentioned to the Vulkan docs Github that this wording is confusing.

I tried several frame compositions as a test of this feature. The frame's structure looks like this:
      |=A=|     |===========B===========|
        1L        2S        3G        4P
      .---.     .---.     .---.     .---.
      |  0|---->|0 0|--.  |  0|+--->|0 0|-->{SCREEN}
      '---'     '---'  |  '---'|    '---'
                       '-------'

The composition is made up of 2 RenderPasses, (A) and (B). The 1st Subpass (1L), in the RenderPass (A), creates a small image that is passed to the 1st Subpass(2S) in RenderPass (B). Pass (2S) renders the 3d scene. Pass (3G) renders a gui. Pass 4P presents the image from previous passes to the swapchain (possibly adjusting brightness, contrast, etc). Passes (2S), (3G), and (4P) are all located within RenderPass (B).
For these tests, RenderPass (B) is the focus. However, RenderPass (A) is also recorded to the primary cmdbuf, so it has some relevancy.

A) Single cmdbuf
For this test, everything is recorded in 1 single command-buffer (primary-level). Everything is re-recorded every frame.
Flags and Settings
Primary cmdbuf flags: none
RenderPass (B) content: eInline
vkCmdNextSubpass 'contents' between 2S and 3G: eInline
Outcome
Success. No validation errors.
Remarks
This is the most basic way to record and submit commands to the GPU. Submitting commands like this should always work.

B) 1 primary cmdbuf, one secondary cmdbuf, reused every frame
For this test, most stuff is recorded in primary cmdbuf. Except in pass (3G), for the GUI, the contents of that subpass are recorded in secondary cmdbuf.
There is no re-recording of either buffers; both are reused every frame.
Flags and Settings
Primary cmdbuf flags: none
Secondary cmdbuf flags: eRenderPassContinue
RenderPass (B) content: eInline
vkCmdNextSubpass 'contents' between 2S and 3G: eSecondaryCommandBuffers
Outcome
Success. No validation errors.
Remarks
This works. Both command buffers are reused correctly.
This test proves that it is possible to mix primary and secondary cmdbufs within the same RenderPass.

C) 1 primary cmdbuf, one secondary cmdbuf, re-record everything every frame
For this test, most stuff is recorded in primary cmdbuf. Except in pass (3G), for the GUI, the contents of that subpass are recorded in secondary cmdbuf.
Flags and Settings
Primary cmdbuf flags: none
Secondary cmdbuf flags: eRenderPassContinue
RenderPass (B) content: eInline
vkCmdNextSubpass 'contents' between 2S and 3G: eSecondaryCommandBuffers
Outcome
Success. No validation errors.
Remarks
If both tests (A) and (B) succeed, then it would be expected that this test would also succeed, which it does.

D) 1 primary cmdbuf, one secondary cmdbuf, re-record primary every frame
For this test, most stuff is recorded in primary cmdbuf. Except in pass (3G), for the GUI, the contents of that subpass are recorded in secondary cmdbuf.
The primary command buffer is re-recorded every frame, but the secondary remains fixed.
Flags and Settings
Primary cmdbuf flags: none
Secondary cmdbuf flags: eRenderPassContinue
RenderPass (B) content: eInline
vkCmdNextSubpass 'contents' between 2S and 3G: eSecondaryCommandBuffers
Outcome
Success. No validation errors.
Remarks
It is thus possible to have fixed secondary cmdbufs, while re-recording primaries.

E) 1 primary cmdbuf, one secondary cmdbuf, Only re-record the secondary cmdbuf.
For this test, the idea is to record the general composition of primary cmdbuf once. Thereafter, only re-record the secondary cmdbuf (pass 3G) every frame, thus reusing the contents of the primary cmdbuf.
Flags and Settings
Primary cmdbuf flags: Tried both with/without eSimultaneousUse
Secondary cmdbuf flags: eRenderPassContinue | (both with/without
eSimultaneousUse)
RenderPass (B) content: eInline
vkCmdNextSubpass 'contents' between 2S and 3G: eSecondaryCommandBuffers
Outcome
Failure
Remarks
The command buffer flag eSimultaneousUse didn't help. Tried putting them on both primary/secondary cmdbuds, to no avail. Therefore, when re-recording the secondary cmdbuf, it is mandatory to also re-record the primary in which it is contained.
Validation Error
Validation Error: [ VUID-vkQueueSubmit-pCommandBuffers-00070 ] 
Object 0: handle = 0x1f8700fb330, name = CmdBuf2nd:0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER; 
Object 1: handle = 0x1f86ffb1680, name = CmdBuf:0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER; 
| MessageID = 0xaeecdc0b | 
vkQueueSubmit(): 
pSubmits[0].pCommandBuffers[0] was called in VkCommandBuffer 0x1f86ffb1680[CmdBuf:0] 
which is invalid because bound VkCommandBuffer 0x1f8700fb330[CmdBuf2nd:0] 
was destroyed or rerecorded. 

The Vulkan spec states: Each element of the pCommandBuffers member of each element of 
pSubmits must be in the pending or executable state 

(https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkQueueSubmit-pCommandBuffers-00070)


F) 1 primary cmdbuf, one secondary cmdbuf, Only re-record the secondary cmdbuf, using extension VK_EXT_nested_command_buffer.
This test is like version (E), except that it enables extension "VK_EXT_nested_command_buffer".
The idea is to see if that extension makes a difference in allowing to re-record secondary cmdbuf without
having to rebuild the first cmdbuf.
Flags and Settings
Tried same flags as test (E), except that also tried:
RenderPass (B) content: eInlineAndSecondaryCommandBuffersEXT
Outcome
Failure
Remarks
Unfortunately, the extension "VK_EXT_nested_command_buffer" didn't make a difference for trying to reuse secondary cmdbuf, without having to rebuild the primary cmdbuf.
Validation Error
Validation Error: [ VUID-vkQueueSubmit-pCommandBuffers-00070 ] 
Object 0: handle = 0x1d0bace61c0, name = CmdBuf2nd:0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER; 
Object 1: handle = 0x1d0bace0e70, name = CmdBuf:0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_COMMAND_BUFFER; 
| MessageID = 0xaeecdc0b 
| vkQueueSubmit(): 
pSubmits[0].pCommandBuffers[0] was called in VkCommandBuffer 0x1d0bace0e70[CmdBuf:0] 
which is invalid because bound VkCommandBuffer 0x1d0bace61c0[CmdBuf2nd:0] 
was destroyed or rerecorded. 

The Vulkan spec states: Each element of the pCommandBuffers member of each element of 
pSubmits must be in the pending or executable state 

(https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.3-extensions/html/vkspec.html#VUID-vkQueueSubmit-pCommandBuffers-00070)



Overall Remarks

It is allowed to mix primary and secondary cmdbufs within the same RenderPass. Each subpass contains commands recorded either to primary cmdbuf, or to secondary. To mix commands to both primary and secondary cmdbufs within the same subpass, that requires extension "VK_EXT_nested_command_buffer". Note that I didn't include a test for this primary/secondary mixing within the same subpass -- it's just that's what that extension is used for.

It's possible to reuse command buffers, including secondary command buffers. Though, there are requirements on the reuse.

It is allowed to reuse secondary cmdbufs whilst reusing its primary cmdbuf. That is, both primary/secondary are recorded, and then subsequently reused together.

It is allowed to reuse secondary cmdbufs whilst re-recording its primary cmdbuf.

It is NOT allowed to re-record secondary cmdbuf, while reusing its primary cmdbuf. Whenever a secondary cmdbuf is re-recorded, the containing primary cmdbuf must also be re-recorded.


There are other types of reuse that I didn't test for. Example, resubmitting primary/secondary cmdbufs to multiple queues in the same frame.
If someone is aware of settings or extension that will allow #5 to work, please mention it. That's the type of reuse I was personally hoping to do.

"That's the type of reuse I was personally hoping to do." That's never going to work. From the standard: "If a secondary moves to the invalid state or the initial state, then all primary buffers it is recorded in
move to the invalid state."

Yeah, that is true. Well, that settles that.

@NicolBolas - If you can please add that quote to your answer, I'll mark it as accepted. Thanks
